# WebSphere ESB is not connected to WebSphere MQ? (Message is not sent)

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-esb

I have written a simple web service as a sample to work with IBM ESB but getting attached error at the time of sending message... seems that ESB is not able to connect to WMQ.

Please let me know if you have any idea or solution.

[image: The error which we are getting at the time of sending message]

Answer (score 1):

The pertinent error here seems to be:

'sc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

The 'sc' command is part of the Windows operating system, you should investigate why it wasn't found. Perhaps it isn't installed, or perhaps the command isn't on the PATH you've got configured in your environment?

On my system 'sc' can be found here:

C:\Windows\System32\sc.exe

Comment: Thanks for your support.